# Loop in JavaScript until a condition is met

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm trying to loop indefinitely until a condition is met...is the following correct?

It seems not to be.

```
    var set = false;
    while(set !== true) {
        var check = searchArray(checkResult, number);
        if(check === false) {
            grid.push(number);
            set = true;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: *Seems not to be.* Really? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Well...I just want to know if I can break out of a loop like this and if it SHOULD work. If it looks right, then the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: How could we possibly know without knowing what `searchArray` does or what `checkResult` & `number` are

Comment: Also add what is your Problem doest it loop infinity or doest stop in the first iteration or or or...

Comment: number - is a randomly generated number.
searchArray - does just that. Searches array for a generated number. It returns either true or false. If the number is not in the array...I adds it to the grid. And changes set to true.

I just wanted to know if my syntax was correct really. 

Thanks so much

:D

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Basically, you can make an infinite loop with this pattern and add a break condition anywhere in the loop with the statement [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break):

```
while (true) {
    // ...
    if (breakCondition) {            
        break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to sleep this function? Dont wanna spam it ..

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus, no it is not possible with this pattern ...

Answer (score 1):

The code will loop while searchArray result is **not false** and until it becomes **false**. So the code is correct if you wanted to achieve such behavior and it's not correct otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go over this. You want the code to loop until the function searcharray() returns true, right?

First, the code creates the variable "set" and sets it to false.

Then while set is *not* equal to true (would suggest using triple equals here), run this code:

Create the variable "check" and set it to what searcharray returns.

If searcharray returns false, it will add a number on to the end of the array grid as a new entry and then set "set" to true.

Then it loops again. If searcharray returned true, it loops again as set is still false. If search array returned false, it does not loop again and skips to the end.

Comment: That's exactly it. Below answer by Nina Scholz seems best solution. No need for another var.